# How can I start an Activity from a non-Activity class?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I have a map view activity that shows a few `OverlayItems`. In the `onTap` method of an overlay, I want to trigger a new activity that shows this overlay photo as a fullscreen, for example.

When I do this inside my overlay class:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(getApplicationContext, FullscreenView.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

.. it can't find an application context, as I am not in the scope of an activity.

When I add a method to my main activity, let's say `startFullscreen`:

```
public static void startFullscreen() {
    if (sCurrentPhoto != null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), FullscreenView.class);
        startActivity(intent);          
    }
}
```

I can not call `getApplicationContext()` and `startActivity()`, because I am in a static context. I need the static method however to call it in the Overlay class like `MainView.startFullscreen()`.

Put simply: **How can I start an Activity from a non-Activity class?**

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Your `onTap` override receives the `MapView` from which you can obtain the `Context`:

```
@Override
public boolean onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView mapView)
{
    // ...

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(mapView.getContext(), FullscreenView.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: When I try to start an activity from a non-activity class (in the same process) I get an exception: "android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag."   (I'm doing this in the context of an intent handler.)

Comment: before the startActivity, add `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`

Answer (score 97):

Once you have obtained the context in your onTap() you can also do:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(mContext, theNewActivity.class);
mContext.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Answer (score 14):

I don't know if this is good practice or not, but `casting a Context object to an Activity object compiles fine.`

Try this: `((Activity) mContext).startActivity(...)`

Comment: Unbelievably, this works. And it's the only solution here that does work for startActivityForResult().

Comment: This is only going to work if the context actually *is* an activity. E.g. I don't think you can cast the application context to an activity.

Comment: Timmmm is right, and btw both ApplicationContext and Activity's BaseContext extends Android.Content.Context which is an abstract class

Answer (score 9):

You can define a `context` for your application say `ExampleContext` which will hold the context of your application and then use it to instantiate an activity like this:

```
var intent = new Intent(Application.ApplicationContext, typeof(Activity2));
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
Application.ApplicationContext.StartActivity(intent);
```

Please bear in mind that this code is written in `C#` as I use MonoDroid, but I believe it is very similar to `Java`. For how to create an `ApplicationContext` look at this [thread](http://mono-for-android.1047100.n5.nabble.com/Custom-Application-class-to-store-global-variables-java-runtime-ClassNotFoundException-td4383621.html)

This is how I made my `Application Class`

```
    [Application]
    public class Application : Android.App.Application, IApplication
    {
        public Application(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(handle, transfer)
        {

        }
        public object MyObject { get; set; }
    }
```