# Android - Switch activities from renderer

Tags: android, opengl-es, renderer, switching

In my Android app I want to switch activities from my renderer. When I create the Renderer I pass context in the constructor. In my Renderer in the onDrawFrame function:

```
public MyRenderer(Context ctx){

    this.context=ctx;
}

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

    testFlag = renderFrame();


    if(testFlag > 0)
    {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this.context, MyActivity.class);
        myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        this.context.startActivity(myIntent);
        testFlag = 0;
        return;
    }


}
```

This calls the onPause() in my main activity which handles some OpenGL staff..

What I get is an error when switching the acivities:

At that point I receive the following error:

***call to OpenGL ES API with no current context ( logged once per thread)***

Can anyone please help me? I realize that this is caused because a call to OpenGL is not made from the OpenGL thread but how do I fix it??

What is the proper way to switch activities from within the renderer?

Answer (score 1):

I used those sources: 
[How can I start an Activity from a non-Activity class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298225/how-can-i-start-an-activity-from-a-non-activity-class) 
[How do I restart an Android Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397361/how-do-i-restart-an-android-activity) 
This is solution to switch activities inside class that is non-Activity class (for example Renderer)

```
    private Context context; 
    public MyGLRenderer(Context context)  {
    super();
    this.context = context;                         
}
```

```
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
            myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            ((Activity)context).finish();
            ((Activity)context).overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            context.startActivity(myIntent);
            ((Activity)context).overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the GLSurfaceView.Renderer docs:

> **Threading**
>   The renderer will be called on a separate thread, so that rendering performance is decoupled from the UI thread. Clients
>   typically need to communicate with the renderer from the UI thread,
>   because that's where input events are received. Clients can
>   communicate using any of the standard Java techniques for cross-thread
>   communication, or they can use the
>   [queueEvent(Runnable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#queueEvent(java.lang.Runnable))
>   convenience method.

You should be able to do your OpenGL calls correctly through such a Runnable, posted from your `onPause()` method.

I don't think the fact that you're initiating the activity switch from the GL thread is part of the issue (it *does* seem a bit weird, but I will assume you have a good reason for it :)).